# Using .NET string formatting, how do I format a string to display blank (empty string) for zero (0)?

Tags: .net, formatting, string-formatting, string.format

I am using a DataBinder.Eval expression in an ASP.NET Datagrid, but I think this question applies to String formatting in .NET in general.  The customer has requested that if the value of a string is 0, it should not be displayed.  I have the following hack to accomplish this:

```
<%# IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDWhole").Trim = "0", "", 
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDWhole", "{0:N0}"))  %>
```

I would like to change the `{0:N0}` formatting expression so that I can eliminate the IIf statement, but can't find anything that works.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting fix, Nick.  I now see how to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [section separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator), like this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDWhole", "{0:N0;; }").Trim() %>
```

Note that only the negative section can be empty, so I need to put a space in the `0` section.  (Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator))

Comment: It's a good day.  I learned something and it's not even 10 a.m. yet!  I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: Almost right, but N0 is a standard format and you need a custom format, e.g. "{0:#,##0;;}".  You don't need to put a space in the third section.

Comment: Caution, this won't work as you think it would: for MSDWhole != 0, you'd get "N<value>". N0 is not supported with group separators. Use "{0:#,0;; }"

Comment: @Joe: you *do* need either a space or `''` for the third group, as an empty group is ignored. {0:+A;-A;} returns +A for 0. With `''` no Trim is needed.

Comment: @Ruben, you're right, it should be a hash digit placeholder, e.g. {0:#,##0;;#}

Comment: Thanks all for the discussion. {0:N0;; } works. @Joe, your last comment entry also works.  BTW, this did not work if the number being formatted was a string containing a number.  It works for 0, but not "0" .

Comment: `It DoubleEmitsBlankWhenZeroInStringFormat = () =>
            string.Format("{0:$#,0;$#,0;#}", 0d).ShouldEqual(string.Empty);` - the hash in the last position works

Answer (score 3):

Given the accepted answer:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDWhole", "{0:N0;; }").Trim() %>
```

The a space is placed in the the 3rd position, however placing a `#` in the third position will eliminate the need to call `Trim()`.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDWhole", "{0:N0;;#}") %>
```

Comment: Dave, I tried this idea and it worked great!  Dropping the trim is definitely an improvement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom method.

```
public static string MyFormat(double value) {       
    return value == 0 ? "" : value.ToString("0");
}

<%# MyFormat(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("MSDWhole"))) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call a function while binding like this

```
<%# MyFunction( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDWhole") ) %>
```

and inside the function make the formatting you want