# Format spec to display blank (empty string) for zero (0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Is there an option in [format specification](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#formatspec) to display zero values as blank, otherwise use format?

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> '{:+010,.2f}'.format(Decimal('1234.56'))
'+01,234.56'
>>> '{:???f}'.format(Decimal(0))
''
>>>
```

UPDATE:

I need the same behavior as here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator

If Python doesn't have it in standard libraries, please confirm this and i will accept it as the answer.

Comment: here is a similar question for .NET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282573/using-net-string-formatting-how-do-i-format-a-string-to-display-blank-empty-st

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can obviously not have one format that will both print with a leading zero, two decimals and minimum 10 wide, and empty at the same time. Printing a zero with the format above correctly gives "+00,000.00". So you will have to make it conditional on being zero or not, whatever you do. And in that case you *can* just skip it. So all of the answers below are correct.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear - i need a formatter option. In the .NET question link it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't currently do it via a Python format specification. Use a conditional expression instead. For example:

```
print(format(a, '+010,.2f') if a else "")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about define a function:

```
def format_cond(val,fmt,cond=bool,otherwise=''):
    return format(val, fmt) if cond(val) else otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have a section separator functionality so you can have different formats for positive, negative or zero numbers in the same string. You'll have to use separate format strings.

Answer (score 0):

I was counting the frequency of occurrence of upper and lower case vowels in a piece of text.

```
# display each vowel and its frequency of both upper and lower case occurrence
for key, value in lower.items():
    print("{:^6}\t{:5}\t{:5}".format(key, value if value > 0 else "", upper[key.upper()] if upper[key.upper()] else ""))

Vowel   Lower   Upper
------  -----   -----
  a        52       9
  e        80        
  i        37        
  o        50       3
  u        21        
        =====   =====
          240      12
```

Answer (score -1):

`format` does lots of things, but this isn't what it is designed for. There is also a very simple solution:

```
if a == 0:
  print("")
else:
  print(format(a, '+010,.2f'))
```

Comment: Ugh, sorry, this is just unpleasant -- you don't need the `==0`, the `print("")` (?!?!), or the `else`.

Comment: i cannot consider this as an answer. i need a format specification option, if it exists

Answer (score -1):

```
if a:
    print(...)
```